# Автоупаковка в обобщениях

Tags: java, generics

Почему в обобщениях можно использовать только оболочки типов? почему нельзя примитивные типы использовать? почему не работает автоупаковка и распоковка?

Comment: Потому, что после компиляции все обощённые типы превращаются в `Object`.

Comment: так что мешает int автоупокавать в Integer и потом привести к Object ?

Comment: Повторяю, к моменту выполнения байткода в нём нет информации о типе, поэтому виртуальная машина понятия не имеет, что какой-то `Object` - это на самом деле целое число.